# How to check that the events happened during 2 consecutive months in last 3 months?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I want to write a query that can detect if particular person (identified by `PersonId`) visited a city at least 1 time per month during 2 consecutive months in the last 3 months.

Is it possible to do using Elasticsearch query language?

I can count the number of times that a person visited a city per month. However, I don't know how to calculate that the visits happened in the last 3 months during 2 consecutive months.

```
GET visits/_search?
{
 "size":0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": {
          "PersonId": "AAA"
        }}
      ]
    } },
   "aggs": {
    "visit_days": {
     "terms" : {
      "field": "Month"
     }
    }
   }
}
```

Besides `Month` (it is a string), I also have `Year` and `Date` (this is date type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can handle the logic of parsing of a date-histogram within an application, that would likely be the best scenario.

Here's an example of how you would at least get buckets for that information:

```
GET visits/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "visit_days": {
            "gte": "now-3M"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "histo": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "visit_days",
        "interval": "month"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And an example output:

```
 {
      "key_as_string": "2017-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "key": 1501545600000,
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key_as_string": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "key": 1504224000000,
      "doc_count": 0
    },
    {
      "key_as_string": "2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "key": 1506816000000,
      "doc_count": 1
    }
```

And then to meet your requirement, parse that response and do something simple like checking the count of the 2nd to last month for 0 (assuming the 3-month restriction is static).